# Angular: Error: The loader ".../src/app/app.component.scss" didn't return a string

Tags: angular

de la noche a la mañana cuando intento levantar la aplicación me aparece ese error

```
Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:/xampp/htdocs/angular/inventario/src/app/app.component.scss' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\angular\inventario'

Error: The loader "C:/xampp/htdocs/angular/inventario/src/app/app.component.scss" didn't return a string.
```

Lo único que instalé fue bootstrap y material.

Busqué el error pero no pude dar con la solución, solo vi este caso similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349503/error-in-the-loader-src-app-app-component-scss-didnt-return-a-string/51564752 pero no logré solucionarlo

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Necesitaríamos un poco más de contexto. A mi concretamente este error me dio cuando migraba una app de CSS a SCSS. Conclusión, eliminar todas las dependencias de node_modules y volver a instalar. Se ve que se me quedo algo residual.